# Component not rendered on button click - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on a react application. I've a top bar with button and I want to render `Registration` component to the onClick function. There's no output with the below, I'm I missing something here?

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react'
import Registration from 'Registration'


export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }


  handleClick () {
    <Registration />
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='top-bar'>
        <div className='top-bar-left'>
          <ul className='menu'>
            <li className='menu-text'>SIS App</li>
            <li>
              <button className='button' type='button' onClick={this.handleClick}>Create Info</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div
    )
  }
}
```

Here is my Registration component:

```
'use strict'

import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class Registration extends Component {
  render () {
    let props = this.props
    let {edit} = props
    let handleChange = props.handleChange()
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration</legend>
        <input name='name'
               value={props['name']}
               type='text'
               placeholder='Your Name'
               onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input name='email'
               value={props['email']}
               type='email'
               placeholder='Email'
               onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input name='phone'
               value={props['phone']}
               type='tel'
               pattern={PhoneNumberPattern}
               placeholder='Phone'
               onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </fieldset>
    )
  }
}
```

And my app.js:

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Header from 'Header'

render(
  <div>
    <Header />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: You're not doing anything in handleClick. What exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick doesn't render new react component.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33840150/onclick-doesnt-render-new-react-component)

Comment: Go through [React JS-State and Lifecycle Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) you would understand much better how to use states and render accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to render the registration component, but you are not defining any place for it to render,

```js
import React from 'react'
import Registration from 'Registration'


export default class Header extends React.Component {
        constructor (props) {
          super (props)
          this.state = {
            registration: false
          }
          this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
        }


        handleClick () {
          this.setState({registration: true})
        }

  render () {

    return (
      <div className='top-bar'>
            <div className='top-bar-left'>
              <ul className='menu'>
                <li className='menu-text'>SIS App</li>
                <li>
                    <button className='button' type='button' onClick={this.handleClick}>Create Info</button>
                      <li>

                </ul>
                {this.state.registration ? <Registration/>: null}
            </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However I suppose ideally you would want to route to your registration component whenever the button is click, your could do that using `dynamic routing` after defining a route for your registration component.

Refer **[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177385/load-new-a-new-component-onkeypress-reactjs/43177465#43177465)**, if you wish to do it this way

Answer (score 0):

In `handleClick` you can change state like this `this.setState({ renderRegistration: true })` and then in `render` function do the following

```
if (this.state.renderRegistration) {
    return '<Registration />';
} else {
    // your existing code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that your `Header` component will render to the screen is what's in the `render` function.

One approach here is to have a flag that controls whether to display the `Registration` component, which is controlled by the button click event.

I don't know where your registration component needs to go, but try something like this:

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react'
import Registration from 'Registration'


export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props)
    this.state = { showRegistration: false }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }


  handleClick () {
    this.setState({ showRegistration: true })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='top-bar'>
        <div className='top-bar-left'>
          <ul className='menu'>
            <li className='menu-text'>SIS App</li>
              <li>
              <button className='button' type='button' onClick={this.handleClick}>Create Info</button>
               <li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        {this.state.showRegistration && <Registration />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct two things, firstly you have to import `Header` correctly in `main.js`, as follows:

**main.js**

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Header from './Header.jsx'

render(
  <div>
    <Header />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Secondly, define and bind `handleChange` function you are using in `Registration` component and provide the area to render the same, a follows:

**Header.jsx**

```
'use strict'
import React from 'react'
import Registration from './Registration.jsx'

export default class Header extends React.Component {
        constructor (props) {
          super (props)
          this.state = { showRegistration: false }
          this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
          this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        }

        handleClick(e) {
          this.setState({ showRegistration: true })
          console.log("The link was clicked");
        }

        handleChange(e) {
          console.log("handleChange was clicked");
        }

  render () {
    let registration = null;
        if (this.state.showRegistration) {
          registration = <Registration handleChange = {() => this.handleChange()}/>
        }
    return (
      <div className='top-bar'>
            <div className='top-bar-left'>
              <ul className='menu'>
                <li className='menu-text'>SIS App</li>
                <li>
                    <button className='button' type='button' onClick={this.handleClick}>Create Info</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
       {registration}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Considering the layout of app, as below:

[image]